# The problem with working in redux, there is a multiple request for data

Tags: redux, react-redux, axios

I create a user profile page:

1. inputs are not filled immediately, because, apparently, the data is received later than the interface is drawn.
2. There are multiple requests that seem to be the same.
3. When I try to add something to the input, redux again requests data (pending, fullfiled), for each input

Please help, I'm stuck

[multiple requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0bHD.png)

userSlice.js

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import axiosInstance from '../../services/axios/index'
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        name: '',
        surename: '',
        patronymic: '',
        email: '',
        is_admin: false,
        is_chief: false
    },
    reducers: {
    },
    extraReducers(builder){
        builder.addCase(getProfileInfoAsync.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.name = action.payload.name
            state.surename = action.payload.surename
            state.patronymic = action.payload.patronymic
            state.email = action.payload.email
            state.is_admin = action.payload.is_admin
            state.is_chief = action.payload.is_chief
        })
    }
})

export const getProfileInfoAsync = createAsyncThunk('users/getInfo', async () => {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get('users/current-detail/')
    return response.data.userInfo
})

export const { } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

ProfileScreen.js

```js
function ProfileScreen (){
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    dispatch(getProfileInfoAsync())
    
    const userProfile = useSelector((state)=>state.user)

    const [name, setName] = useState(userProfile.name)
    const [surename, setSurename] = useState(userProfile.surename)
    const [patronymic, setPatronymic] = useState(userProfile.patronymic)
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(userProfile.email)

    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(userProfile.is_admin)
    const [isChief, setIsChief] = useState(userProfile.is_chief)

    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    


    return (
        <FormContainer>
            <Form style={{'marginTop': '10px'}}>
            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlainTextName">
                    <Form.Label column sm="2">
                    Имя
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="10">
                    <Form.Control type='text' value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}/>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlainTextSurename">
                    <Form.Label column sm="2">
                    Фамилия
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="10">
                    <Form.Control type='text' value={surename} onChange={(e)=>setSurename(e.target.value)}/>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlainTextPatron">
                    <Form.Label column sm="2">
                    Отчество
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="10">
                    <Form.Control type='text' value={patronymic} onChange={(e)=>setPatronymic(e.target.value)}/>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlaintextEmail">
                    <Form.Label column sm="2">
                    Email
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="10">
                    <Form.Control plaintext readOnly defaultValue={email} />
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlaintextPassword">
                    <Form.Label column sm="2">
                    Пароль
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="10">
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Введите новый пароль" />
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="formPlaintextAgainPassword">
                    <Form.Label column sm="2">
                    Пароль еще раз
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm="10">
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Введите новый пароль" />
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" controlId="Switches">
                    <Col sm="10">
                        <Form.Check 
                        checked={isAdmin}
                        disabled
                        type="switch"
                        label="Админ?"
                        id="isAdminSwitch"
                        />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm="10">
                        <Form.Check 
                        checked={isChief}
                        disabled
                        type="switch"
                        label="Начальник?"
                        id="isStaffSwitch"
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
            
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Сохранить
                </Button>
            </Form>

        </FormContainer>
    );
    }
     
    export default ProfileScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation again (yes, i was not smartest kid in my family), I did the following.
in userSlice.js:
Extended initialState

```json
initialState: {
        userInfo: {
            name: '',
            surename: '',
            patronymic: '',
            email: '',
            is_admin: false,
            is_chief: false
        },
        status: 'idle',
        error: null
        
    },
```

Added handlers for other states

```js
extraReducers(builder){
        builder.addCase(getProfileInfoAsync.pending, (state, action)=>{
            state.status = 'loading'
        })
        .addCase(getProfileInfoAsync.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.status = 'succeded'
            state.userInfo.name = action.payload.name
            state.userInfo.surename = action.payload.surename
            state.userInfo.patronymic = action.payload.patronymic
            state.userInfo.email = action.payload.email
            state.userInfo.is_admin = action.payload.is_admin
            state.userInfo.is_chief = action.payload.is_chief
        })
        .addCase(getProfileInfoAsync.rejected, (state, action)=>{
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.error.message
        })
    }
```

Added selector for userInfo

```js
export const selectUser = state => state.user.userInfo
```

In ProfileScreen.js:
With the help of `useEffect` I "handle" these states

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const userProfile = useSelector(selectUser)

    const userStatus = useSelector(state => state.user.status)

    const [name, setName] = useState(userProfile.name)
    const [surename, setSurename] = useState(userProfile.surename)
    const [patronymic, setPatronymic] = useState(userProfile.patronymic)
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(userProfile.email)

    const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(userProfile.is_admin)
    const [isChief, setIsChief] = useState(userProfile.is_chief)

    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (userStatus=='idle'){
            dispatch(getProfileInfoAsync())
        }
        else if (userStatus == 'succeded'){
            setName(userProfile.name)
            setSurename(userProfile.surename)
            setPatronymic(userProfile.patronymic)
            setEmail(userProfile.email)
            setIsAdmin(userProfile.is_admin)
            setIsChief(userProfile.is_chief)
        }
        
    }, [userStatus, dispatch])
```

For my "problem" the solution was this.